# Odoo - How to Import Odoo Database Dump File

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo

I'm new with Odoo and I want to see just the database tables (the data is not really important) from database IDE e.g. DataGrip. There are 2 options to download the database from Odoo:

- zip (includes filestore)
- pg_dump custom format (without filestore)

I create a temporary Postgres database to import the file. It seem like the `dump.sql` from `zip (includes filestore)` work when I imported, but I get some errors like:

- `The JDBC driver currently does not support COPY operations.`
- `multiple primary keys for table "stock_rules_report" are not allowed`
- etc

Log summary:

```
Summary: 11748 of 11748 statements executed, 4886 failed in 16 s 642 ms (1525350 symbols in file)
```

Environment:

- Odoo 12
- Postgres 10 & 13
- DataGrip

Answer (score 1):

Take the custom format dump and restore it with the PostgreSQL client tool `pg_restore`:

```sh
pg_restore --schema-only -d targetdb -h dbhost -p 5432 -U postgres dumpfile
```

That will restore only the table definitions without the data.

Answer (score 1):

Backup and Restore using  url:port/web/database/manager
https://odoosolution.blogspot.com/2021/01/odoo-database-backup-restore.html